# Jupyter Sagemath horizontal scroll output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sage

I have a large matrix and when I print the matrix in Sage, the Jupyter notebook is wrapping the rows of the matrix, which makes visualizing the matrix very difficult. Instead, I want to enable horizontal scrolling. I've seen various solutions about changing the size of the container window, but this doesn't give me horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Good question.  In the (now nearly deprecated) Sage notebook, you could cycle between several versions of this in output, and I'm pretty sure scrolling was an option.

Comment: @kcrisman yes, that's precisely what I'm thinking of. In the old notebook, I could cycle to infinite horizontal scroll so that I could see a large matrix without having the columns wrapped, which is an immense hassle.